# Access property of a concrete class using a generic class with the help of reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, properties

I can do the same stuff using interface implementation and the dependency injection knowledge, But I just want to know the use of generics in this case.

Suppose I have few classes which contains same number of properties of same type and in certain cases it contains same method of identical signature as well. For example the classes called Dog, Cat, Tiger etc. Now, inside the operator class there is a Main method from where the program will execute.

In the above case how can I reduce my code using generics so that, I can pass only the desired class as a parameter to access the method and get/set property based on the particular class?

> Note: I can do that using interface but I don't want to.

Comment: The classic way to do this, if you have classes "Dog, Cat, Tiger, etc." is to use use either inheritance from a common (possibly abstract) class (say Animal), or to use an Interface all the classes implement (say IAnimal) .NET generic types really don't mesh well with your requirements. The "Curiously Reoccuring Template Pattern" in C++ (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) fits the bill better. However that can't be implemented using .NET generics.

Comment: Don't want to use interface, I want the goal to be achieved using generics.

Comment: Then use a base class instead of an interface.

Comment: If you cannot, in fact, write *generic code* that compiles based on the *type constraints* that you can apply to your generic type parameters, it's a sign that generics is the *wrong tool* for the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I generally use Interface in this case, but I mentioned in the question that the answer of this question will give the answer of another question which is written in this problem description. He wanted to know the generic way of his problem which is now ON HOLD. But in the answer, he did not get any desired answer. So I created this question for him to get the answer.

Comment: If someone asks for the best way to use a sledge hammer to drive decking screws into fine victorian furniture to mend it, do you *help them find an answer* or point out to them that they're *doing things wrong*. Sure it *seems* more "helpful" to offer an answer but if your answer ends up producing matchsticks, you've not really helped.

Comment: I agree, But If the owner of the furniture urges to use screw driver instead of sledge hammer and he/she wants to know the way to use it even if sledge hammer is good to use in his/her case, Then shouldn't I tell him the way to use if any exists? I think, I can show him the way letting him know that he could have chosen the better way.

Comment: If someone wants black shirt, then will I buy him white shirt?

Comment: This isn't "the customer is always right" territory. Generic code that *compiles* but can *never possibly work* for a certain type parameter substitution is a broken generic implementation. Don't help someone to build one. If they want "generic code with no type safety", they should know about `dynamic` already and be using that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177871/discussion-between-rashedul-rubel-and-damien-the-unbeliever).

Answer (score 0):

Yes Reflection is the option but it is not suggested because it eats up lot many memory.

See this probably you can try this way,

```
class MainApp
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Cat cat = new Cat(4, "Black", true, "White");

        Tiger tiger = new Tiger(4, "Black", true, "Yellow");

        Cow cow = new Cow(4, "Black", true, "Black");
    }
}

public class Animal
{
    public int Legs { get; set; }

    public string EyeColour { get; set; }

    public bool Tail { get; set; }

    public string SkinColour { get; set; }

    public Animal(int legs, string eyeColour, bool tail, string skinColour)
    {
        this.Legs = legs;
        this.EyeColour = eyeColour;
        this.Tail = tail;
        this.SkinColour = skinColour;
    }
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    public Cat(int legs, string eyeColour, bool tail, string skinColour) 
        : base(legs, eyeColour, tail, skinColour)
    {
    }

    public int MyPropertyCat { get; set; }
}

public class Tiger : Animal
{
    public Tiger(int legs, string eyeColour, bool tail, string skinColour) 
        : base(legs, eyeColour, tail, skinColour)
    {
    }

    public int MyPropertyForTiger { get; set; }
}

public class Cow : Animal
{
    public Cow(int legs, string eyeColour, bool tail, string skinColour)
        : base(legs, eyeColour, tail, skinColour)
    {
    }

    public int MyPropertyForCow { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: I generally use Interface in this case, but I mentioned in the question that the answer of this question will give the answer of another question which is written in this problem description. He wanted to know the generic way of his problem which is now ON HOLD. But in the answer, he did not get any desired answer. So I created this question for him to get the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Generics aren't really a good fit in this case.  What your looking for is called duck typing and the closest you can get in C# is to use the dynamic keyword.

```
public void FillAddress(string type)
{
    if (_addressDetails == null) throw new Exception($"{nameof(_addressDetails)} must not be null.");

    dynamic details = _addressDetails;
    dynamic addressSource;

    if (type == "Manager")
    {
        addressSource = _manager;
    }
    else if (type == "TeamLead")
    {
        addressSource = _teamLead;
    }
    else if (type == "Employee")
    {
        addressSource = _employee;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Unrecognized type", nameof(type));
    }

    details.AddressLine1 = addressSource.AddressLine1;
    details.AddressLine2 = addressSource.AddressLine2;
    details.AddressLine3 = addressSource.AddressLine3;
}
```

(I don't recommend doing this.  I commented on the other post that your friend should try to use partial classes to apply an interface to the types that have common properties.)

Comment: Thanks, But did you read the question? Did the question want to know the generic way? Please read the question first and be specific in giving your answer. I did not want a suggestion rather I wanted to know the generic class use.

Comment: @Rashedul.Rubel the generic way is to use the interface! You posted the reflection way and pretended it answered the question. With the dynamic way, you don't need generics, so there is no need to add them. Your answer is the same as my answer but with reflection instead of dynamic and with pointless generic. Why are you even asking the question if you aren't going to listen to the answers?

Comment: I specified in the question by mentioning GENERIC CLASS but not GENERIC WAY